# What is the center of gravity of 2 Rings of Dia/Thickness B/b & R/r that have been fused?

Tags: geometry

Think of a wrist bangle and a finger ring (i.e. round wires curled into perfect circles). The bangle has a Diameter B and thickness b. The ring has a Diameter R and thickness r.
let me state the obvious that R < B and b < B and  r < R.

Normally, for a ring of uniform density, it's center of gravity may be considered to be at it's center.

We now place the Bangle on table and place the Ring inside of it so that they are touching. In fact we go a step further and glue them together.

Question is:

> What is the center of gravity of 2 Rings of Dia/Thickness B/b & R/r respectively -- with the smaller ring placed inside the larger and fused together in one plane.

i.e. how much will the center of gravity of the Bangle shift after you have fused the ring to it. Ignore glue mass.

Consider them both made from same metal i.e same density. And extra marks if you can calculate considering different densities for both.

Comment: You can apply the general rule: center of mass of two bodies is the weighted average of their centers of mass, where the weight is their mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, the center of mass of two bodies is the weighted average of their individual centers of mass. If $M_B$ and $M_R$ are the masses of bangle and ring (which can be computed as volume $\times$ density), the center of mass of the compound object lies on the line connecting the centers of bangle and ring, at a distance from the center of the bangle given by:
$$
x_G={M_R\over M_B+M_R}{B-R\over2}.
$$
Volumes of bangle and ring can be computed using the formula for the volume of a torus:
$$
V_B={1\over4}\pi^2 B b^2,\quad V_R={1\over4}\pi^2 R r^2.
$$